I try to model my data file I get an stuck:giap.dat(offset 2316):expected number context: >>> T2 <<< 0.8213
param tau {t in Time, p in All_Product} >= 0;
data;  # Define sets and their cardinalities set Time := T1 T2 T3 T4 T5;           # |T| = 5 set Donors_Deliver := 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8;    # |DD| = 8 set Collection_Donors := 1 2;       # |CD| = 2 set Financial_Donors := 1;           # |FD| = 1 set Existing_FoodBank := E1 E2 E3 E4; # |OB| = 4 set Potential_Sites := 1;            # |PB| = 1 set Served_Charities := 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16;    # |SC| = 16 set Hold_Charities := 1 2 3;            # |HC| = 3 set FoodGroup := 1 2 3;            # 1: dry, 2: fresh, 3: frozen set Levels := 1 2 3;               # 1: small, 2: medium, 3: large  # Define the Individual_Food sets set Individual_Food[1] := 1 2;                 set Individual_Food[2] := 3 4;                 set Individual_Food[3] := 5;  # Define financial parameters param VTI :=      [1,1,1] 2.00, [1,2,1] 7.50, [1,3,1] 10.00,     [2,1,1] 1.50, [2,2,1] 5.00, [2,3,1] 6.00,     [3,1,1] 1.00, [3,2,1] 3.50, [3,3,1] 4.00;  # Fixed cost of serving a beneficiary institution in period t param FC := E1 10 E2 10  E3 10 E4 10;  # Cost of operating one unit of storage capacity for product family k at food bank b in period t param VSt :=     [1, 1, 1] 0.0250, [1, 1, 2] 0.0500, [1, 1, 3] 0.1250,     [2, 2, 1] 0.0500, [2, 2, 2] 0.1000, [2, 2, 3] 0.2500,     [3, 3, 1] 0.0375, [3, 3, 2] 0.0750, [3, 3, 3] 0.1875,     [4, 4, 1] 0.0375, [4, 4, 2] 0.0750, [4, 4, 3] 0.1875,     [5, 5, 1] 0.0375, [5, 5, 2] 0.0750, [5, 5, 3] 0.1875;  # Cost of handling one unit of food products belonging to family k at food bank b in period t param VHt :=     [1, 1, 1] 0.1250, [1, 1, 2] 0.2500, [1, 1, 3] 0.6250,     [2, 2, 1] 0.2500, [2, 2, 2] 0.5000, [2, 2, 3] 1.2500,     [3, 3, 1] 0.1875, [3, 3, 2] 0.3750, [3, 3, 3] 0.9375,     [4, 4, 1] 0.1875, [4, 4, 2] 0.3750, [4, 4, 3] 0.9375,     [5, 5, 1] 0.1875, [5, 5, 2] 0.3750, [5, 5, 3] 0.9375;  # Total budget available in period t for facility location and capacity acquisition decisions param O :=     1 250,     2 250,     3 250,     4 250,     5 250;  # Financial donation of donor d to purchase food products in period t param Qtilde :=     [1, 1] 100, [2, 1] 150, [3, 1] 200,      [4, 1] 100, [5, 1] 120;  # Cost of purchasing one unit of food product p in period t param tau :=     T1 0.4740,     T2 0.8213,     T3 0.7899,     T4 0.8406,     T5 4.4340;  # Cost of disposing one unit of food products belonging to family k in period t param phi :=     1 0.055,     2 0.055,     3 0.055;  # Cost of CO2 emissions due to transportation of one unit of a food product, per km param omega := 0.00075;  # Quantity of food product p supplied by donor d in period t param Qt :=      [1,1,1] 400, [1,1,2] 600, [1,1,3] 500,     [2,1,1] 450, [2,1,2] 650, [2,1,3] 550,     [3,1,1] 420, [3,1,2] 620, [3,1,3] 520,     [4,1,1] 430, [4,1,2] 630, [4,1,3] 530,     [5,1,1] 410, [5,1,2] 610, [5,1,3] 510,          [1,2,1] 300, [1,2,2] 500, [1,2,3] 400,     [2,2,1] 350, [2,2,2] 550, [2,2,3] 450,     [3,2,1] 320, [3,2,2] 520, [3,2,3] 420,     [4,2,1] 330, [4,2,2] 530, [4,2,3] 430,     [5,2,1] 310, [5,2,2] 510, [5,2,3] 410,          [1,3,1] 200, [1,3,2] 300, [1,3,3] 250,     [2,3,1] 250, [2,3,2] 350, [2,3,3] 300,     [3,3,1] 220, [3,3,2] 320, [3,3,3] 270,     [4,3,1] 230, [4,3,2] 330, [4,3,3] 280,     [5,3,1] 210, [5,3,2] 310, [5,3,3] 260;  # Storage and transport capacity levels available (in tonnes) param Mlk :=     [1,1] 1011.00, [1,2] 168.50, [1,3] 6.74,     [2,1] 2022.00, [2,2] 1348.00, [2,3] 33.70,     [3,1] 4044.00, [3,2] 2696.00, [3,3] 134.80;  param Nlk :=     [1,1] 168.50, [1,2] 134.80, [1,3] 16.85,     [2,1] 337.00, [2,2] 269.60, [2,3] 33.70,     [3,1] 842.50, [3,2] 505.50, [3,3] 67.40;  # Minimum storage capacity param M_min:      1 2 3 :=     1 3639.60 1122.21 94.36     2 269.60 23.59 3.37     3 1533.35 208.94 10.11     4 930.12 87.62 20.22; # Maximum storage capacity param M_max:      1 2 3 :=     1 4788.77 4087.81 215.68     2 269.60 208.94 10.11     3 1533.35 208.94 10.11     4 2298.34 2470.21 43.81;  # Minimum transport capacity param N_min:      1 2 3 :=     1 1944.49 0.00 0.00     2 0.00 0.00 0.00     3 647.04 0.00 0.00     4 1297.45 0.00 0.00;  # Maximum transport capacity param N_max:      1 2 3 :=     1 2594.90 1297.45 90.99     2 647.04 647.04 90.99     3 647.04 647.04 90.99     4 1297.45 1297.45 90.99;giap.dat, line 65 (offset 2316):         expected number context:   >>> T2 <<<  0.8213,
reset;  model giap.mod; data giap.dat;  # Set the solver to Gurobi #option solver gurobi;  # Solve the model #solve;  # Display the parameters to ensure they are loaded correctly display VTI, FC, VSt, VHt, O, Qtilde, tau, phi, omega, Qt, M_min, M_max, N_min, N_max;
ampl: include "giap.run";  giap.dat, line 65 (offset 2316):         expected number context:   >>> T2 <<<  0.8213,

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It is hard to read since it is not clear where a new lines start, and there are comments. Something must be wrong with the assignment to tau, since it is indexed over Time and Products, and in the data assignment you have:
param tau := T1 0.4740, T2 0.8213, T3 0.7899, T4 0.8406, T5 4.4340;
So it seems like you are writting the Time index but not the product one.
As you are having problems with the data, I highly recommend you using the Ampl Python api to load the data since it is much more comfortable, and you do not need to take care of the ".dat" format.
Documentation:
https://amplpy.ampl.com/en/latest/
Example (in a Jupyter notebook):
https://colab.research.google.com/github/ampl/colab.ampl.com/blob/master/authors/fdabrandao/chatgpt/christmas.ipynb
Please, it would be really helpful if you formatted correctly and provided specific context for your problem, this is not the first topic with these issues.
